# Output a property with PHP5 and method chaining

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

I am playing with PHP5 and method chaining, following several StackOverflow examples.
I would like to set up a generic show() method able to print only the desired property, please see the example:

```
<?php

class testarea{

  public function set_a(){
    $this->property_a = 'this is a'.PHP_EOL;
    return $this;
  }

  public function set_b(){
    $this->property_b = 'this is b'.PHP_EOL;
    return $this;
  }

  public function show(){
   echo var_dump($this->property_a); // ->... generalize this                                                                                                                     
   return $this;
  }

}

$ta=new testarea();

$ta->set_a()->set_b();
$ta->show();

?>
```

This echoes `string(10) "this is a "`.

What I would like to do is a generic show() method which shows only the property that the `set_a()` or the `set_b()` methods have setted.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a private array property:

```
private $last = NULL;
private $setList = array();
```

In your `set_a()` and `set_b()` use:

```
$this->last = 'line A';
$this->setList['a'] = $this->last;
```

and

```
$this->last = 'line B';
$this->setList['b'] = $this->last;
```

Your `show()` method then reads:

```
foreach ($this->setList as $line) {
  var_dump($line);
}
```

or if you only need the last property set:

```
return $this->last;
```

Comment: I am new to OOP and method chaining so this could be a bad practice. But my idea is that the following method could inherit something from the last property setted, or do not inherit if a parameter is specified.